# SignalR - Pushing notification to servers

Tags: c#, signalr

When I try to broadcast a message to all clients, I can trigger client's javascript code from server and get the job done.

But this time my aim is to trigger a method in all servers. For example, when roles of a user changed in one server, I want to warn other servers about this operation and I want to make other servers retrieve updated user role list for particular user.

Is it possible to do this with SignalR? Can a server behave like a client (browser)?

Comment: Are your servers using a backplane ?

Comment: Yes @gobes , they are using Redis server as backplane.

Comment: I don't think it's natively possible to do such a thing... but as you are using redis, you can subscribe to some channel and then publish the refresh message on it, triggering the refresh mechanism on the subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

Let's say you have the following hub:

```
public class TheHub : Hub
{
    public void RoleChanged(int userId)
    {
        Clients.All.roleChanged(userId);
    }
}
```

On all the listening servers, you'd have to do:

```
var _connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:1234/signalr");
var _theHub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("TheHub");

_myHub.On<int>("RoleChanged", userId =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Changed user's Id: " + userId);
    });

_connection.Start().Wait();
```

To invoke the RoleChanged event, do:

```
_myHub.Invoke("RoleChanged").Wait();
```

Comment: Where should I place 2nd code segment in ASP.NET server side code? In addition, is `_connection.Start().Wait();` persistent, or is it executed only once?

Comment: You can place the 2nd code in Global.asax.cs file's Application_Start method. You need to call it only once.